# Scrollview making view invisble

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have multiple views in my layout inside a `ScrollView` and there is a validation on certain items, in case of any error I scroll to that view using the following:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.scrollTo(0, view.getBottom());
        view.getParent().requestChildFocus(view, view);
    }
});
```

But the problem here is as soon as this code runs the scroll is achieved but the view passed to this makes itself invisible. After removing this everything is working fine.

I think this is some sort of bug with scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is inside `scrollView` and you have added `scrollTo()` method in your view not in `scrollView`. Replace `view.scrollTo(0,view.getBottom())` to `scrollview.scrollTo(0, view.getBottom())`.
Try below solution this might work for you.

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollview.scrollTo(0, view.getBottom());
        view.getParent().requestChildFocus(view, view);
    }
});
```